# Конструкции со ссылками. Где подлежащее и сказуемое?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

В описании под видео часто встречаются подобные конструкции:

> Телеграм-канал Алексея Венедиктова — https:/t.me/avst55
> Сетка вещания — http:/echo.msk.ru/schele

Можно ли считать первую часть подлежащим, а вторую — сказуемым? Для двух случаев это применимо? Это спорные конструкции?

Как быть со следующим случаем тогда?

> Я в instagram — instagram.com/qwerty

По мне, здесь никак нельзя признавать первую часть подлежащим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строго говоря, здесь во всех трех примерах (разве что во втором можно поспорить насчет устоявшегося термина) между подлежащим и сказуемым имеются второстепенные члены предложения, а это означает, что тире не требуется. А в третьем случае еще и подлежащее выражено местоимением.

Но тире ставится не только из синтаксических соображений, но и если логически или интонационно требуется что-то выделить. Здесь как раз этот случай: автор намеренно ставит тире там, где имеется прерывание речи и переход к ссылке. Вы можете представить как автор замолкает на этом месте и делает жест рукой, указывая на ссылку.